# Upload file using CGI from Windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, command, cgi

I need to upload a file to a web server via command line on Windows. The web server has a CGI script to facilitate this which we can call from Mac using CURL. For example, from Mac we call this:

```
curl -m 60 --form "file=@/tmp/myfile.txt" http://mywebserver.com/cgi/upload.cgi
```

The CGI script accepts the file and puts it where we want it. Can we call this in a similar way from Windows natively?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Windows build of cURL:
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html